# CSS text float alignment

Tags: html, css, xhtml

See the image:

[image]

I want, without using Javascript that if the text of .elements (view the html at the end) is too long, that it separate is placed on two lines in the grey area.

"Hello world! Hello StackOverFlow!" is the text that should be separated.

** If you think that something is missing, or I didn't explain myself enough, just ask I will try my best to provide you what you want to know ;)

## HTML

```
<div class="filter">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="center">
        <div class="arrow">Search Filter Research Text Test</div>
        <div class="head"></div>
        <div class="element"><div>Hello World! Hello StackOverFlow!</div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.table .filter {
    height: 44px;
    position: relative;
}


.table .filter div {
    height: 44px;
}

.table .filter .left {
    width: 7px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    background: url('../images/Tableau/filtre/gauche.png') no-repeat;
}

.table .filter .right {
    width: 7px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background: url('../images/Tableau/filtre/droit.png') no-repeat;
}

.table .filter .center {
    background: transparent url('../images/Tableau/filtre/centre.png') repeat-x;
    left: 7px;
    right: 7px;
    position: absolute;
}

.table .filter .center>div {
    float: left;
}

.table .filter .center .arrow {
    background: url('../images/Tableau/filtre/fleche-centre.png') repeat-x;

}

.table .filter .center .head {
    width: 13px;
    background: url('../images/Tableau/filtre/fleche.png') no-repeat;   
}

.table .filter .center .element {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}

.table .filter .center .element>div {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Your image and your code do not match. Partly because you wrote your code in French. When using an English-based language, and posting on a mostly-English site... plesae use English.

Comment: can you create an example in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Kolink Why you want the images paths to be english, this is irrelevant. What i'm missing is the `table` part

Comment: table part doesn't affect at all the code (except for the width). Here is the jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/XkgA7/2/

Comment: @Bondye Loooking at the image and seeing the text "Hello World", then finding "Bonjour le monde" in the code, is only helpful if you happen to be bilingual English/French. Thankfully, I am. Others might not be.

Comment: @Kolink more irrelevant comments

Comment: @Bondye Your irrelevant comments are more irrelevant than the supposedly irrelevant comments that provoke them. Since the matter has been resolved, and the code actually matches the image now, there is nothing more to discuss on this subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/XkgA7/21/

The height needs to be adjusted but this appears to be the behavior you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, but every space written add a new line, not exactly what I'm looking for, but it is a start ;)

Comment: Can you clarify what what behavior you would like to see, I'd be happy to adjust it to your needs.  Also a +1 one for effort would be appreciated :)

Comment: I would, but it require 15 reputation, which I don't have... As for the behavior, I simply want it to reach the end before skipping to the next line.

Comment: When you say 'the end' could you please be more precise.

Comment: Okay now I understand you meaning, please check the fiddle again.  Adding a space to the text no longer automatically creates a new line

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following CSS to the `.element`:

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

This will ensure that your text is never too long to fit in its container.

However, should this fail, then there is a problem elsewhere in the CSS and the container itself is being made too big. This would almost certainly be because of the `width: 100%` in the `element>div`. Try removing that.

Comment: This indeed fail, because the width 100% on element>div is only the text width instead of the element witdh...